# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Intellisense for JQuery Mobile???

Tags: visual-studio-2010, jquery-mobile

I am trying to setup intellisence for JQuery Mobile in VS2010 SP1. I cannot find a VSDOC file which I have achieved for JQuery. The only other suggestion was to install "html_5_jqm.xsd" as described in https://github.com/hakanson/intellisense-jquery-mobile which I cannot get to work. I am running 64bit Win7 and executed the relevant REG file. My feeling is to get hold of a VSDOC for JQMobile, but I unsure if one exists yet.

All thoughts appreciated,

Ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the HTML Source Editing toolbar enabled, select the option "Jquery Mobile" in the dropdown, normally it should be running.